# Converting array of unicode byte to string

Tags: python, arrays, unicode, websocket

From some external module I receive array with unicode symbols and can not convert it to string.

> ```
>    print(data)
>    print(type(data))
>    print(type(data[0]))
>    print(len(data[0]))
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
>    array('B', [99, 100, 99, 100, 99, 100, 99, 100, 99])
>    <type 'unicode'>
>    <type 'unicode'>
>    1
> ```

So I just need to get a string 'cdcdcdcdc', but type of data[0] is unicode, although 'B' (int) presented. All my tires finished with errors or I got same one array (not a string) when print.

upd:I tried

> ```
>    rets=''
>    for i in xrange(len(data)):
>        rets += chr(int(ord( data[i] )))
>    print( rets )
> ```

Comment: In python in an array can only be one type

Comment: The issue is you are printing `data` instead of `rets`. Try replacing the last line with `print( rets )`.

Comment: sorry, there must be print(rets) and it issue same one:
array('B', [99, 100, 99, 100, 99, 100, 99, 100, 99])

Comment: Correcting a couple of things:  The python that you are using is python3.  Python doesn't have arrays instead, we use lists and they can be any type that we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputs are an evidence that data is in fact this unicode string:

```
data = u"array('B', [99, 100, 99, 100, 99, 100, 99, 100, 99])"
```

(weird to have got that, but it is the only possibility)

`ast.litteral_eval` cannot processes arrays, so you will have to use the evil `eval` to change this in a true array:

```
from array import array
arr = eval(str(data))
```

**Never** do that if data could come from an external source, because eval-ing uncontrolled data can allow execution of arbitrary code: *CAVEAT EMPTOR*

But once this is done, arr is a nice array of unsigned chars. You can easily make it a string that way:

```
''.join([chr(i) for i in b])
```

---

Anyway, above is just a workaround. The real solution would be to find how such a weird string was produced and fix that.

Comment: Ok, but it's not worked
    >>> eval(str(data))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @AntonGusev: did you use `from array import array` first? The error suggests that you just used `import array`...

Comment: Yes, import array was done. I use python2.6.6, may be it reason?

Comment: @AntonGusev: I *willingly* wrote `from array import array`. It is the only way for `array` to be interpreted as a type and not a module. But anyway as I wrote in my last edit you really should try to fix the code that gave you that string!

Comment: Many tanks, I change "from array import array" instead "import array", and now "eval(str(data))" work fine! I got an 'cdcdcdcdc' after ''.join([chr(i) for i in arr])!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use eval to convert a string to a python object in this case a list(unicode can be handled many times as a string. So eval will work with unicode aswell). If data[1] is already a list just remove eval from the print statement.

Then use map to turn every int into a character with chr. This can then be made into a string with "".join

```
 print ("".join(map(chr,eval(data[1]))))
```

output:

```
 "cdcdcdcdc"
```

Edited:
try it in a few statements to see where it goes wrong

```
print (eval(data[1])) #check if eval works
print (type(eval(data[1]))) #check if the type that evel returns is a list
print (type(map(chr,eval(data[1]))[0])) #check if the types in the list are strings
print (map(chr,eval(data[1]))) #check if you get a list with strings
```

Comment: This not worked for me, I got error
    print "".join(map(chr,eval(data[0])))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: srry i made a mistake you need ofcourse use data[1]

Comment: Just change to data[1], now it says:
NameError: name 'r' is not defined

Comment: what do you get when you type :

        print (type(data[1]))

Comment: NameError is a weird error, because the only variable used is data and not 'a' or 'r', but if type(data[1]) is a list you should not use eval

Comment: I mean because of 'eval' - it tries to compute something wrong sintax?

Comment: print "".join(map(chr,data[1]))
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: No, eval(data[1]) doesn't work (error NameError: name 'r' is not defined as before). Why do you mean it's a list? It's an array.